# Would like to use CentOS in VMware as a DHCP server for other virtual machines

Tags: dhcp, vmware-workstation, centos-7, dhcp-server

I'm using three VMs: one is CentOS, while the others are Kali and Ubuntu. I would like to use the CentOS one as the DHCP server and others as the host.

Even though they can ping between each other, and firewalls are configured to allow the DHCP, still the DHCP host machine won't get the IP from the CentOS machine. Instead they get the IP range from the Main Host machine.

The network type on VMware is bridged.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can’t have multiple DHCP servers on the same network. Not only are you going to have trouble with your virtual machines, you’re going to mess up your real machines. Because you bridged the network they are all on the same network. You have to change the network type to NAT.

Comment: Thanks 
It worked after using NAT as the connection method  and turning off VM DHCP service